# SQL query to get all rows when there is no matching row in left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
person (pid, pname)
personSamples(sid,pid,sampleName)
groups(gid,groupName)
groupPersons(gpid,gid,pid)
grouppersonSamples(gpsid,gid,sid)
```

Whenever a person is added to a group (i.e. in `groupPersons` table), I add some selected samples of person in `grouppersonSamples` table.

The requirement is, if I do not insert any row in `grouppersonSamples` then select all from `personSamples` for a given person and group.

What I have to do is *left join* with `grouppersonSamples` and check if there is no matching row in `grouppersonSamples` then execute another query to select all from `personSamples` for given pid.

Is there any way to get all in single query?

Comment: Can you insert the query you have already tried in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will give you group-person-samples(gid, sid) for a given person(pid) which are not already present in grouppersonSamples table:

Assume pid of the given person is 3. I've not considered the gid of the group in which this person is added. If you wish to consider a specific group, add the gid filter in the following query similar to pid = 3 condition.

```
select T1.gid, T1.sid from
    (select gid, sid from groupPersons, personSamples where groupPersons.pid = personSamples.pid and groupPersons.pid = 3) as T1
LEFT JOIN
    (select grouppersonSamples.gid, grouppersonSamples.sid from personSamples, groupPersons, grouppersonSamples where personSamples.pid = 3 and personSamples.pid = groupPersons.pid and grouppersonSamples.gid = groupPersons.gid and grouppersonSamples.sid = personSamples.sid) as T2
ON T1.gid = T2.gid and T1.sid = T2.sid where T2.gid IS NULL;
```

The first query extracts all possible group-person-samples(gid, sid) for given person (say pid = 3) and the second query extracts all group-person-samples(gid, sid) present in grouppersonSamples table for given person.

Then the LEFT JOIN works as MINUS operation and gives the group-person-samples(gid, sid) for given person which are not already present in grouppersonSamples table.

Also you can use the above query in insert statement as follows:

```
insert into grouppersonSamples(gid, sid) (<above query>);
```

P.S.: I've used LEFT JOIN to perform minus operation as Mysql does not support MINUS operator. You can directly use MINUS operator if your DBS supports it.